# How an user choose a number of tickets and then ask for the prize of each ticket an make a total?

Tags: java

Traying to make a program that ask for number of tickets between 1 to 5.
Then I need to know the prize of each ticket, asking the user to put it.
Then make a sum of the total.

```
    //kb = keyboard, t = tickets, val = prize, sm = sum tickets
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = 0;
    double val = 0,sm = 0;

    //this is a loop just for know the ticket number.
    do {
        System.out.print("How many tickets do you have?[max 5]");

        while(!kb.hasNextInt()){
            kb.nextLine();
            System.out.println("This is not valid, try again.");                
        }
        t = kb.nextInt();
    } while ((t <= 0 || t >= 6));
```

The problem or where I get stuck is here.(It's needed to be with for)

```
    //With the for I can ask for the value of each ticket
    for (int i = 1; i<=t ;i++) {
        System.out.println("Ticket número "+i+" es de:");
        val = kb.nextDouble();
    }
```

How I sum the diffents prizes of each ticket to make the total sum?

Comment: Just add each `val` to `sm`, inside the loop: `sm = sm + val;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove `val` entirely, and simply add to the sum directly:

```
for (int i = 1; i<=t ;i++) {
    System.out.println("Ticket número "+i+" es de:");
    sm += kb.nextDouble();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 1; i<=t ;i++) {
    System.out.println("Ticket número "+i+" es de:");
    val = kb.nextDouble();
    sm = sm + val;
}
```